# Blur cell image on cell button click in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiblureffect

In table view cell i have an image and a button now i want to blur the image on the click of button

I have the following code :-

```
func blurEffect(){
    let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    blurView.frame = imageView.bounds
    view.addSubview(blurView)
}

// I am Calling blur effect on at tick button action as below


@objc func tickButton(btn : UIButton){
    blurEffect() 
}


 //In tableView

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = MealTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MealCell

    cell.imgMeal.image = UIImage(named: mealImage[indexPath.row])

    cell.btnTick.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MealPlanViewController.tickButton(btn:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You should put this code in your `cell` class. Not in `ViewController`.

Comment: I want to fly!!

Comment: Please don't ask i want, Ask about your problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this code -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = MealTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MealCell

    cell.imgMeal.image = UIImage(named: mealImage[indexPath.row])
    cell.btnTick.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnTick.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MealPlanViewController.tickButton(btn:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

you have to add blur view on particular cell , in which you click .....
and you can get cell in func by button tag like

```
 @objc func tickButton(btn : UIButton){
    let index = IndexPath.init(row: btn.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = tbl.cellForRow(at: index) as! newTbl
    let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
    blurView.frame = cell.img.bounds
    cell.img.addSubview(blurView)
}
```

But you have to save blur cell's indexPath or row and draw it every time when table reload in cellForRowAtIndex method. 
Because when table view reload or reuse same cell , it will show blur.

Answer (score -1):

Change following func (Assuming it is in `MealCell` class)...

```
func blurEffect() {

  let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
  let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)

  blurView.frame = self.imgMeal.bounds
  self.addSubview(blurView)
}
```

You can create IBAction of button with in tableview cell i.e. `MealCell` class.

```
@IBAction func tickButton(_ sender : UIButton){
    blurEffect() 
}
```

Comment: how do you get the `cell.imgMeal.bounds` in outside the tableview

Comment: your answer is not correct, need more code for output

Comment: Nice catch, Thanks Kartik...Ans. modified.

Comment: same ? again, how do you call the `blurEffect() `  in button action, if yo do like, it will call the current class function not a cell class \

Comment: @Anbu.karthik consider this code in `MealCell` that has `imgMeal`outlet.

Comment: @Kamran - how do you call the `blurEffect()` method in button action

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned that `MealCell` contains the `imgMeal`.

Comment: @MahendraGP - how do you call the blurEffect() method in button action

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Consider `tickButton` action is also in `MealCell`

Comment: Consider every bit of code in this question/answer except code inside `cellForRowAt` is in `MealCell`.

Comment: no is not a valid answer for question, plz update your answer based on previous answer

Comment: `self.addSubview(blurView)` will not add blur view to cell.